# Cannot find my signal on logic analyzer of keil uVision for LPC2148

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, keil, lpc

I am trying to run my PWM program on keil for lpc2148. This has 10% duty cycle. However, I can see the signal on Port0 (P0.21).
Here is my code. I am quite confident it is right.

```
#include<lpc214x.h>

int main()

{
PINSEL0=0x00000000; // P0.0 to P0.15 pins of PORT0 as GPIO
PINSEL1=0x00000400; // P0.21 Pin of PORT0 as PWM
PINSEL2=0x00000000; // P1.16 to P1.31 pins of PORT1 as GPIO
/*Configure the PLL block and set the CCLK and PCLK at 60 MHz */
PLL0CON=0x01;
PLL0CFG=0x24;
PLL0FEED=0xaa;
PLL0FEED=0x55;
while (!(PLL0STAT & 0x00000400));
PLL0CON=0x03;
PLL0FEED=0xaa;
PLL0FEED=0x55;
VPBDIV=0x01;
/* Setup and initialize the PWM block */
PWMPCR=0x00; // Single Edge PWM Mode
PWMPR=60000-1; // Resolution of PWM is set at 1 mS
PWMMR0=10; // Period of PWM is 10 mS
PWMMR5=1; // Pulse width of PWM5 is 1 mS
PWMMCR= (1<<1); // PWMTC is reset on match with PWMMR0
PWMLER= (1<<5)| (1<<0); // Update Match Registers PWMMR0 and PWMMR5
PWMPCR= (1<<13); // Enable PWM5 output
PWMTCR= (1<<1); // Reset PWM TC and PWM PR
PWMTCR= (1<<0)| (1<<3); // Enable PWM Timer Counters and PWM Mode
//PWMMR5 = 1;
//PWMLER = (1<<5); //Update Latch Enable bit for PWMMR5
}
```

[image: screenshot]
Please help.

Comment: my bad. Thank you for correcting sir.

Comment: Your `main()` will run to completion then terminate - what happens then is undefined.  You should enter a loop (possibly with a `_WFI` instruction to reduce power consumption).  Expecting the run-time to entering a loop on exist rather then simply resetting is not reliable.

Comment: ... ignore the `_WFI` suggestion - that is for Cortex-M - who knew you could still get  ARM7TDMI devices?!

Answer (score 2):

The Keil debugger's "logic analyser" tool watches specific *global* variables via SWO trace.  Your code has no global variables and you have not stated what you are monitoring.

On real hardware *only* global variables can be monitored.  Peripheral registers and I/O pins can only be monitored in simulation as specified at https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_db_dbg_logicanalyzer_restrictions.htm

To get a trace that follows your PWM, you will need to implement a PWM interrupt handler that either copies the state of the output pin to a global, or (better) reads the `PWMIR` register and copies that to a global variable and/or sets the global to the state inferred by the `PWMIR` register.  Then you monitor the global variable rather than the pin directly.

For example:

```
volatile bool pwmout = 0 ;
volatile bool pwmmatch = 0 ;

__irq void PWM_ISR( void )
{
    pwmmatch = PWMIR  ;

    if( (PWMIR & 0x0001) != 0 )  // MR0 = 1
    {
        pwmout = 1 ;
    }
    else if ( PWMIR & 0x0020 )  // MR5 = 1
    {
        pwmout = 0 ;
    }
    PWMIR = 0 ; // clear interrupt

    VICVectAddr = 0x00000000;
}
```

And you can then monitor `pwmout` and/or `pwmmatch` in the logic analyser.

I am not familiar with your specific microcontroller so the above may need some tweaking.  Obviously you will also need to enable the interrupt handler - something like:

```
VICVectAddr0 = (unsigned) PWM_ISR; /* PWM ISR Address */
VICVectCntl0 = (0x00000020 | 8); /* Enable PWM IRQ slot */
VICIntEnable = VICIntEnable | 0x00000100; /* Enable PWM interrupt */
VICIntSelect = VICIntSelect | 0x00000000; /* PWM configured as IRQ */
```

but I am just copying existing examples - no guarantees.

Finally at the end of your `main()` add an *infinite loop* to prevent `main()` from terminating into who knows where:

```
for(;;)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: Sir, I have added PORT0 to my logical analyzer and then I have applied mask as 0x00200000 for observing P0.21 signal. I can see only a zero signal. Whereas on PORT0 I could actually see the P0.21 going high and low continuously.

Comment: @newbie99 :  OK, then you have your answer - you cannot monitor an I/O pin.  There is a work-around - will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the code is right, but to observe the waveform using the Keil logic analyzer, you need to specify the correct port pin notation. Instead of using **"P0.21"** you should use **"PORT0.21"**.

[I have attached the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgUUv.png)

Then press enter and see the results.

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFcQl.png)